# Browse to upload from a certain location

Tags: html, upload

Is it possible to limit the location of browsing for a file?

I mean when a user choose a file, he is only allowed to choose files from location **Documents** for example

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="./../upload_file.asp">
<input required="required" name="dname" type="file" accept=".doc,.docx"  />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is the browser's job and user preference, not possible as far as i know.